# Java netbeans How to Insert/ save Jlist Elements into Sql Database (sql server 2008)

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, netbeans

[image: Jlist Elements]

There are 3 Elements in the Selected Subjects Jlist.
I want to insert these 3 elements into Database with 3 rows.
That means I want to run one insert sql query 3 time (the list size).

here is my sql statement

```sql
INSERT INTO ClassSubjects (SchoolCode,ClassCode,GroupName,SubjectCode)
VALUES (@SchoolCode,@ClassCode,@GroupName,@SubjectCode)
```

Here is my java code for save button:
I have already connected to db here is my java codes :

```
String School_Code = txt_SchoolCode.getText();
String ClassCode = txt_ClassCode.getText();        
String group = com_GroupName.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(ClassCode.isEmpty() ){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All Fields are Required !!");}
    else{
        try{
            String sqlSchoolCode = "Exec Proc_set_ClassSubjects ?, ?, ?, ?";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sqlSchoolCode);
            pst.setString(1, School_Code);
            pst.setString(2, ClassCode);
            pst.setString(3, group);
            pst.setString(4, subject);           

            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved Successfuly");
            btn_ClassSubject_new.doClick();

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

How can I do this ?
I am using netbeans (java application) and sql server 2008

Comment: you need many things: a for loop, some JDBC and the jTDS driver for your database. And a little googling might help too. And before doing any of this you should read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I have already connected to db

Comment: Great, so which is the problem you are trying to solve ? You should decide whether to use a direct sql insert or the exec you have in your code.

Comment: I can insert one row using this codes but I want to insert all Jlist element. using loop but how can I put these element into array and how can I use loop for this?